# Composing two of three given functions to obtain $2^{x+1} - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

A problem I'm facing involves three given functions. I need to compose two of them to obtain $2^{x+1}-1$. The three functions I'm allowed to use are

- $f(x) = 2x-1$
- $g(x) = 1/x$
- $h(x) = 2^x$

It would be great if there was a detailed explanation as to how you got the answer too. Thanks!

Comment: Is it $$2^{x+1}-1$$?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't format it well.

Comment: There are three ways to try composing two functions, and 6 ways to try composing all three. If those failed you could try further compositions I suppose, but it's pretty obvious any further compositions will fail. You only need to compose two functions, so just try the three combinations. This is not a homework-solving site, so you need to show some effort and context for your problem.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking maybe fh(x+1). Is that right? I'm not very sure.

Comment: For future reference, here's a MathJax reference - the markup language used to render math text here. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Oh thank you. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Consider the functions $f$ and $h$. This answer will be more complicated than simply plugging things in, you'll need to make use of some algebraic properties.

In particular, the property that $$a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$$

---

**Solution:**

So, $f(x) = 2x-1, h(x) = 2^x$. We know we want to get two to the something, so we should apply $h$ at some point, and we kind of want a $-1$ to appear at some point, so that's why we choose $f$.

Sadly beyond that stuff like this is largely guess and check (such as other possible functions or the order to apply them); I'll say right off that the right composition is $f \circ h$.

This gives us the function composition

$$(f\circ h)(x) = f\left( h(x) \right) = 2\cdot 2^x - 1$$

We make use of the property I noted earlier: $2\cdot 2^x = 2^{x+1}$. Thus

$$(f\circ h)(x) = 2^{x+1} - 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's the detailed explanation as to how to get the answer:

Compute all applicable compositions, i.e., $f(g(x))$, $g(f(x))$, $f(h(x))$, $h(f(x))$, $g(h(x))$, $h(g(x))$. Then check if any of these equals (or can be simplified to) the desired function of $x$.

Comment: We must not compute all these possibilites, since the solution should be $$2^{x+1}-1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Of course, we can stop this extremely finite task as soon as we happen to run into a valid solution. -- Of course one could make one's life a lot easier by observing that the desired composition has $0$ in ist range and is defined at $0$, hence $g$ cannot occur in the composition. Moreover, the desired function has negative numbers in its range, which excludes $h$ as outer function. Hence $f\circ h$ is the only candidate, and if we rely on the validity of the problem statement, we can write it down without further testing ...

Answer (score 0):

But $$h(f(x))=2^{2x-1},h(g(x))=2^{1/x}$$ which gives not your solution, so $$f(h(x))$$ leads to your solutions